# How to compile an Angular2 TypeScript application to a single file?

Tags: typescript, commonjs, angular, systemjs, tsc

I realize that I can compile my application with `tsc my_app.ts --target system` and it will generate a SystemJS-wrapped file for each imported module, which is awesome, but it generates anonymous (nameless) functions, so I can't just concatenate them to a single file.

I thought about making this question "how to compile TypeScript to named SystemJS modules", but my goal is just to compile my Angular2 app to a single file, SystemJS or not.

Comment: See [--outFile](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options)

Comment: @EricMartinez Unfortunately, the `--out`/`--outFile` option does not work with the `--module` option (eg. if you have imports) https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1544

Comment: I've posted an updated answer, since TypeScript added this functionality in version 1.8

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `--outFile` option works with the `--module` option (for AMD and SystemJS) since TypeScript 1.8, so this can be done natively. [Here's the changelog](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#concatenate-amd-and-system-modules-with---outfile). TypeScript also automatically pulls all the dependencies that don't reside in external modules, so it's enough to only compile the main app file.

If Angular 2 doesn't switch away from SystemJS, the way to bundle your app in a single file should be as simple as compiling it with options like `tsc app.ts --target ES5 --module system --experimentalDecorators --moduleResolution node --emitDecoratorMetadata --outFile app.js`

After that it should be possible to bootstrap the application with something like:

```
<script src="/bower_components/system.js/dist/system-register-only.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app');
</script>
```

Comment: Can't we do this in a `tsconfig.json` file?

Answer (score 4):

For the web:

1. Use the TypeScript compiler to compile to JavaScript.
2. Use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) on the JavaScript to combine it to a single file.

An easier way of doing this though is to use [tsify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsify). It's a browserify plugin that compiles TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell you tsc compailer where to put your js files after tsc compile (command: tsc -w). The two parameter in the tsconfig.js file tells TypeScript compailer to put all js out put into one file in a directory is

```
"outDir":"dist/",
"outFile": "dist/app.js"
```

My full tsconfig.js is as below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir":"dist/",
    "outFile": "dist/app.js"
  }
}
```