# Bundling Angular 2.0 source files into one vendor file for deployment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deployment, angular, linemanjs

I'm starting new project which will be based on some legacy code which was written using https://github.com/linemanjs/lineman-angular-template `lineman-angular-template` and Angular 1.5 components

But all new stuff i want to write as Angular 2 components. And i'm looking how to 
concat all source code from angular@ folder into one file let's say vendor.js

Previously i saw such variant [How to compile an Angular2 TypeScript application to a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201005/how-to-compile-an-angular2-typescript-application-to-a-single-file)

```
src="/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"
```

but now in node_modules/@angular there is no more `bundles/angular2.dev.js`

I can't use cdn for it. I need to store everything on my server.
Can you suggest me some tool or smth like that? 
Angular-cli also won't work for this case.

Comment: i've found this thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614743/how-to-prepare-release-version-with-systemjs-and-gulp will try to follow